# Store instance of constantly changing variable in another variable in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a small program with an algorithm to iterate through n number of parcels to find a certain weight `numWeight`. After each iteration, the weight of a parcel is increased. When a solution is found, the solution should be stored in the `solutions` variable. As such, when a solution is found, (when `currentWeight == numWeight`) I want the current instance of `comb` to be stored in an index of the `solutions` arraylist. However, when try and store `comb` in `solutions`, the instance stored continues to change with `comb`. How would I get it so that `solutions` could store an instance of `comb` as it is at the time that line executes? The code snippet in question is as follows:

```
    public void solution2(){
    BookCombination comb = new BookCombination(numParcels, mailClass);
    ArrayList<BookCombination> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentWeight;
    while (!stopCalc){
        currentWeight = comb.getWeight();
        if (currentWeight == 0){
            break;
        } else if (currentWeight == numWeight){
            solutions.add(comb);
            comb.increaseWeight();
        } else {
            comb.increaseWeight();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new `BookCombination` object at each time you add one in the list.
Otherwise you use the same for next iterations.

Creating exactly the same object would not make really sense :

```
 comb = new BookCombination(numParcels, mailClass);
```

I think that you should increment maybe the number of parcels or something in this way to test other combinations.

Try it :

```
public void solution2(){
    BookCombination comb = new BookCombination(numParcels, mailClass);
    ArrayList<BookCombination> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentWeight;
    while (!stopCalc){
        currentWeight = comb.getWeight();
        if (currentWeight == 0){
            break;
        } else if (currentWeight == numWeight){
            solutions.add(comb);
            comb = new BookCombination(numParcels++, mailClass); // change here               
        } else {
            comb.increaseWeight();
        }
    }
}
```